# How can I draw five circles around one circle using Draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

I'm trying to create a diagram for my presentation.

However, I'm a bit stuck and not sure how to achieve this particular layout.

Could you kindly share your knowledge on how to draw like the image I've attached?

[image: 5Vs of Big Data]

Comment: For anyone who has the same problem,

This image might be helpful.

Simply download it and import it into your Draw.io.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCp1j.jpg